# Adding minutes to date in Swift adds extra hour

Tags: swift, date, time

My code is supposed to get a date from a date picker and then add a day (1440 minutes) to it and then update the date picker to reflect that. 
 Problem is it adds a day plus one hour.

```
let originalDate = dtPickerBed.date
var dateAlarmBedLocal = originalDate.date.adding(minutes: 1440)
//save dateAlarmBedLocal to db here
dtPickerBed.date = dateAlarmBedLocal
```

I should also mention that "date" is from this extension:

```
extension Date {
    func adding(minutes: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minutes, to: self)!
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why add 1440 minutes instead of adding 1 day? Keep in mind that you are probably dealing with a daylight saving issue here. Another reason to add 1 day and not 1440 minutes.

Comment: oh my, I think you are right. I'll check

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked: I should have added 1 day (thus allowing Swift to handle daylight savings).

```
let originalDate = dtPickerBed.date
var dateAlarmBedLocal = dtPickerBed.date.adding(day: 1 )
//save dateAlarmBedLocal to db here
dtPickerBed.date = dateAlarmBedLocal

extension Date {
    func adding(day: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: day, to: self)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

rmaddy is correct.  The issue was daylight saving time.